# Consume webservices in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-phone-8

I have wcf webservices and I want to consume them in windows phone 8. It works fine when I run the application on an emulator but when I try to put it on a device, the error "The remote server returned an error not found" occurs.

```
{
    ServiceReference2.GetPositionClient client;
    client = new ServiceReference2.GetPositionClient();  

    client.getData1Completed += new EventHandler<ServiceReference2.getData1CompletedEventArgs>(sendData);
    client.getData1Async(111, 121);
}

public void sendData(object sender,ServiceReference2.getData1CompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dd.Text = "The Response Come from Server is ::  " + e.Result + "     " + count++;
        }
        catch (Exception e3) { ddd.Text = "3" + e3.InnerException.Message; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that the services aren't accessible to the phone. If they are installed on the desktop you are developing on then you need to access them through the shared WiFi network that you have at home.

I have seen people have the issue where their phone was only connected to the mobile network and therefore their development server wasn't accessible.

Check the URL you are connecting to is accessible. perhaps put it in the browser on the phone and ensure the meta data page comes up.

If the network address works from the phone, check the services are exposed to other machines. Some development web servers only allow access from the localhost

Comment: when i enter and address of webservice on windows phone 8 internet explorer it shows the page... and i am using iis 8.0...